# Should supervisor and worker process be registered as global? -Erlang

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

I just started learning Erlang for a month and was curious to know whether both supervisor module and worker module should be registered as global in a singleton process?

Comment: Do you mean "global" as in registered for availability across all Erlang nodes in a cluster, or "global" as in registered for availability within a single Erlang node?

Comment: Yes, for availability across all Erlang nodes in a cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't "register" a **module** as global, you don't register a module at all. If a module is loaded on a node then any other module evaluated in any process on that node can call functions in the original module. No registering or importing or anything else necessary.

If you mean registering a **process** as global then it depends which nodes are are expected to be able to find the process. If it is only to be reached from the same node the a local `register/2` is enough. If, however, you want it to be globally accessible then you need to register it on all nodes which you typically do using the `global` module and with the `{global,Name}` argument when starting supervisors and behaviours.

**EDIT:**

OK, the only processes that really needs to be globally registered are the ones that you need to be globally accessible, which in this case is probably only the worker process. The supervisor probably needs only local registering, if any at all.

Note that registering the supervisor, either locally or globally, will **NOT** by default register the worker process even if it is its child. You have to explicitly register each process.

Comment: My bad :) I meant **process**. I am running a singleton gen-server process (counter) across multiple nodes. So the supervisor process should be registered as global or worker should be registered as global or both should be registered as global?

Answer (score 0):

The rule is simple: you should register the process you are going to communicate with by name.

If you are going to communicate with supervisor, then you have to register supervisor. If you are going to communicate with worker - you should register worker.

In my practice I had to register workers more often, and only had to register supervisors implementing `simple_one_for_one` strategy that were used as process factories